# How do I get the last word in each line with bash

Tags: linux, bash

For example i have a file:

```
$ cat file

i am the first example.

i am the second line.

i do a question about a file.
```

and i need:

```
example, line, file
```

i intent with "awk" but the problem is that the words are in different space

Comment: Your "second line" is not on the second line due to the empty lines, please give less ambiguous examples in the future.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try

```
$ awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' file
example.
line.
file.
```

To get the result in one line as in your example, try:

```
{
    sub(/\./, ",", $NF)
    str = str$NF
}
END { print str }
```

output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
example, line, file,
```

Pure bash:

```
$ while read line; do [ -z "$line" ] && continue ;echo ${line##* }; done < file
example.
line.
file.
```

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl, could you add explanations to each code section, like: "this code prints the last field received by awk by printing `$NF`"?

Comment: could you explain echo ${line##* };

Comment: @code4cause - just goto https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html and search for `##` or just try it in the shell.

Comment: Doesn't return anything if there is just one word. $ echo "foo" | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'
$

Comment: jfyi NF holds the number of fields

Answer (score 97):

You can do it easily with grep:

```
grep -oE '[^ ]+$' file
```

(`-E` use extended regex; `-o` output only the matched text instead of the full line)

Comment: It should be `grep -oE '[^       ]+$'`, you want see the tab here due to browser behaviour, but anyways, this consider tab spaces as well, or better yet you can do `grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+$'`

Answer (score 57):

You can do something like this in awk:

```
awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Edit: To avoid empty line :

```
awk 'NF{ print $NF }'
```

Comment: That would also print the empty lines

Answer (score 20):

Another way of doing this in plain bash is making use of the `rev` command like this:

```
cat file | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | tr -d "." | tr "\n" ","
```

Basically, you reverse the lines of the file, then split them with `cut` using space as the delimiter, take the first field that `cut` produces and then you reverse the token again, use `tr -d` to delete unwanted chars and `tr` again to replace newline chars with `,`

Also, you can avoid the first cat by doing:

```
rev < file | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | tr -d "." | tr "\n" ","
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution! I appreciate the thinking!

Comment: @CaptainWoof "simpler" :-D  It's certainly one I've gone to in the past!

Answer (score 10):

tldr;

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file.txt | paste -sd, | sed 's/,/, /g'
```

For a file like this

```
$ cat file.txt
The quick brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog.
```

the given command will print

```
fox, over, dog.
```

How it works:

- `awk '{print $NF}'` : prints the last field of every line
- `paste -sd,` : reads `stdin` serially (`-s`, one file at a time) and writes fields comma-delimited (`-d,`)
- `sed 's/,/, /g'` : `s`ubstitutes `","` with `", "` `g`lobally (for all instances)

References:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 9):

there are many ways. as `awk` solutions shows, it's the clean solution

sed solution is to delete anything till the last space. So if there is no space at the end, it should work

`sed 's/.* //g' <file>`

you can avoid `sed` also and go for a `while` loop.

```
while read line
do [ -z "$line" ] && continue ;
echo $line|rev|cut -f1 -d' '|rev
done < file
```

it reads a line, reveres it, cuts the first (i.e. last in the original) and restores back

the same can be done in a pure bash way

```
while read line
do [ -z "$line" ] && continue ;
echo ${line##* }
done < file
```

it is called parameter expansion

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me , the following did:

```
grep -o '\S*$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a perl one-liner for last word:

`perl -lane 'print "$F[-1]"'`

... where `-a` gives autosplit into `@F` and `$F[-1]` is the last element.

To turn into list with commas:

`perl -ane 'print "$F[-1]" . (eof() ? "\n":",")'`